# Inheritance with boost data types

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, ambiguous, mpfr

This might be an XY problem, so I’ll put the original situation into context:

I am writing some templated code with for intended use with the data types: double, boost::mpfr, boost::mpfi, boost::interval.  For most of these data types, boost provides a very similar interface, but there are some differences.  The most challenging difference that I’m dealing with is that I would like to specify the details in the conversions between these types (e.g., boost::mpfr typically rounds to nearest, but for a conversion between boost::mpfr and boost::interval, I need to use the backend and specify rounding schemes).

The solution that I considered is to use inheritence along with assignment/explicit casting.  The beginning of the code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

class mpfr : public mpfr_float{
public:
    mpfr() : mpfr_float(0) {}

    template<typename Number>
    mpfr(Number val=0) : mpfr_float(val) {}};

int main(){
    mpfr val1=2.3,val2=3.4;
    val1+val2;
    return 0;}
```

When I try to compile this, I get an ambiguous call error with the following three options (from boost/multiprecision/detail/et_ops.hpp):

1.

```
template <class B>
inline detail::expression<detail::add_immediates, number<B, et_on>, number<B, et_on> >
operator + (const number<B, et_on>& a, const number<B, et_on>& b)
```

2.

```
 template <class B, class V>
 inline typename enable_if<is_compatible_arithmetic_type<V, number<B, et_on> >, detail::expression<detail::add_immediates, number<B, et_on>, V > >::type
 operator + (const number<B, et_on>& a, const V& b)
```

3.

```
 template <class V, class B>
 inline typename enable_if<is_compatible_arithmetic_type<V, number<B, et_on> >, detail::expression<detail::add_immediates, V, number<B, et_on> > >::type
 operator + (const V& a, const number<B, et_on>& b)
```

After all this, I have the following pair of questions:

1. Is this an XY problem, i.e., is there a better option?
2. If this is a reasonable solution, is there a simple way to avoid the ambiguity error?

Comment: Why not create your own rounding functions which have overloads for all the types you want to support, with the correct semantics?

Comment: Can you suggest a uniform way of converting between the number types?  boost::mpfr has the rounding rules hard-coded in mpfr.hpp, so how much of boost_mpfr would I need to rewrite?

Comment: I'm not sure. You haven't exactly pointed out which choices were made (and why they don't suit you). So, if you already know this, I'll leave it to you. That's not... really a programming error, rather a functional decision. However, if you find that the design of Boost's mpfr backend is a burden for developers (because they make arbitrary choices), please do suggest improvements to the maintainers of Boost Multiprecision